# Are heroku config variables encrypted before transmission?

Tags: heroku

Heroku will `git push` over HTTP [unless SSH keys are configured](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys). Are config variables set by `heroku config:set` sent over SSH once SSH is available?

I understand heroku config variables are [allegedly safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680859/are-heroku-config-vars-safe-for-sensitive-information). I just want positive confirmation on this one.

**EDIT**

As a temporary solution, it's possible to set config variables in [your dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/slqc/settings), which is served using HTTPS.

Comment: Heroku's HTTP Git endpoint uses HTTPS, so it's encrypted either way as part of the transit.